# NAND Logic Function Help

Tags: logic

I have a 4 input logic function (ABCD) that I have to construct on a logic trainer using ONLY NAND and Inverter Gates.

We were originally given the following function:

```
F(ABCD)= Sum m(0,1,2,3,4,5,7,14,15)
```

Which I have, through use of a K-map, derived this formula from:

```
(~A ~B) + (~A ~C) + (~A D) +ABC
~ means Not
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Because I have Ors, but I can only use NANDs and Inverters.

Comment: In general, we have $A+B=\sim((\sim A)*(\sim B))$, where $*$ is the NAND operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All gates can be made from NAND gates.
Here is an OR gate made from NAND gates:
[image: diagram]

Also, this should belong in electronics I believe.

For your comment: I assume the + means OR, so you would do ((~A~B)NAND(~A~B))NAND((~A~C)NAND(~A~C)) as the first OR gate.

Comment: So I NAND ~A ~B together, then later NAND it with ~A ~C?